# What's the best way to follow up on potential work from a client?

Tags: contracts, consulting

I am a web developer and a sales guy.

I am confused about how to ask a potential client about moving forward on a project we've discussed, such as if it's been awarded to someone else or it's dumped because of the budget.  What is the polite way to do this?  Generally, I do the following, but I am not sure if it's polite or not:

> Greetings!
>
> I just wanted to know if you have any update on your project as our
>   team is eagerly waiting to finalize the things and start this project
>   asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - yes - nothing wrong with the words you have used.

A respectable client will not be offended and appreciate your interest even if they don't award you the contract.

If they are offended, then the issue is their side, not yours and you're probably lucky not to cross commercial paths.

Work on your confidence when approaching a client - your lack of confidence can hurt you almost as much as your over confidence. Find a balance.

Best of luck!

Comment: It sounds like you are new to consulting - have a read of an answer I wrote elsewhere http://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/8576/how-to-build-a-startup-freelance-software-qa-in-the-us/8585#8585